# Behavior of the solution of the equation $f'' = -x f $ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

This is the Airy equation, and its two independent solutions are $Ai(-x)$ and $Bi(-x)$. Both of which oscillate with a decaying amplitude but an increasing frequency as $x\rightarrow \infty $.

That means a general solution has also similar behavior.

Can anyone give **a direct proof** that a general solution of the equation does not diverge as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Have you tried using power series methods?

Comment: The standard approach is to represent the solution to the equation as an integral transform then apply the method of steepest descents to obtain an approximation. See section 2.2.1 of [these notes](http://math.arizona.edu/~meissen/docs/asymptotics.pdf).